# I have three voltages with different grounding. How can I measure them by using A/D converters with the common ground?

Tags: voltage, adc, ground, measurement, voltage-measurement

I would like to measure three voltages (V, Vs and Vx) by using 3 channel A/D converters.
The problem is that no matter how I arrange the A/D converters on the circuit, two of the measurement points would have a common reference point whereas one would have different reference point. Take for example I use the bottom pin as a reference point. I could work out Vs and V with no problem, but then I have Vx which is not connected to that reference point. The 3 channel A/D converters must have the same common reference point. Is there any ways to make this measuring possible?

[image]

Additional information : Sorry, I forgot to state that Zs is fixed complex impedance and Zx is variable complex impedance. So all voltages are AC with different phases. As the phases are different, V cannot be obtain easily by only subtraction other two voltages.

Comment: You sure you don't want to combine all the grounds? We need more information, like a circuit diagram. There's a webpage inbuilt circuit editor. And what's the point of showing us a voltage divider?

Comment: @Bradman175 Yes, I am sure. The circuit in the figure is all of my circuit. It is not a normal voltage divider circuit as Zx and Zs are complex impedances. This circuit is named 3 voltage circuit. It is used in impedances measurement application.

Comment: @Bradman175 The circuit in the figure is not just an example but it is a practical circuit I will use.

Comment: @Yossiri, V=Vs+Vx. It does not matter that Z is complex.

Comment: @Yossiri I see 2 voltage levels and a ground. Is this AC instead?

Comment: @Bradman175 G is AC source.

Comment: @Bradman175 three voltage levels not two. V Vx and Vs.

Comment: @Chupacabras Thank you, I understand your point. Vx = V - Vs but it needs phasor subtraction. It means that I must know the amplitude and phase of all voltages. But A/D is equal to DC voltmeter. So I will know only amplitudes of V and Vs which are not enough for calculation of Vx.

So I need another method that measure amplitude of V Vx and Vs so that I can calculate all of their phases.

That is why I need to measure Vx. But the problem is that 3 channel A/D has common ground.

Comment: But this completely different question. OP is that you want to measure 3 voltages by ADC. ADC measures current value of voltage. You need to measure just 2 voltages at the same time and use formula Vx=V-Vs. No need to use some kind of different grounds. If you want to calculate complex values of v(t), than it is another question beyond your OP.

Comment: @Chupacabras You cannot subtract them without knowing their phases.

Comment: @Chupacabras If I measure V Vx and Vs with "vector voltmeter", I can subtract them. But in this system, I will use A/D converter which is a "non-vector voltmeter".

Comment: ADC does NOT measure complex values nor phases. ADC measures instantaneous voltage. And you CAN subtract instantaneous values, there is no problem with that.

Comment: @Yossiri, you OP was about measuring voltage by ADC! You got answers. If you want to make something like "vector volmeter" than you should formulate it that way, because it is beyond your current OP.

Comment: Wait wait wait. Like @Chupacabras said, you only need to measure V and Vs where they would have the same reference point, then do maths by V-Vs to get Vx. What's the deal here?

Comment: @Chupacabras Thank you very much. You are right. I was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can measure Vx by measuring V , then measure Vs and substract Vs from V.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to state that Zs is fixed complex impedance and Zx is variable complex impedance. So all voltages are AC with different phases. As the phases are different, V cannot be obtain easily by only subtraction other two voltages.

Comment: @Yossiri you can measure V and you can measure Vs then by subtraction you can get to Vx.

Comment: Exactly as the the current is shared by all the elements. Complex subtraction still takes into account the different phases or angles. Best to convert Polar form to Rectangular form to do complex addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the AC signal, you will need to ensure that you measure the values simultaneously and measure enough points to get a time series, then use a FFT to extract the magnitude and phase from the time series. You then either can sum the time series and FFT again to get the phase and magnitude of V, or represent the parts as complex numbers and add them.

Comment: Sorry I know FFT and DFT. But what is the FFD? Fast Fourier ... ?

Comment: @Yossiri an unrelated acronym I use at work so much I typed the wrong thing. Fixed, thanks.